# Why am I getting IndexError: list index out of range for this function?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, glob

I am trying to concatenate a list of xlsx files. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob


files = glob('DS*.xlsx')
files_combined = pd.concat((pd.read_excel(x).assign(filename = x) for x in files))
```

I get

```
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

I did a lot of research and it seems that the problem people suspect is that glob returns a blank list. However, when I change my code to

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

files = glob('RC*.xlsx')
print(files)
```

I get a list of the files I am looking to concatenate. I have tried changing my code to

```
  import pandas as pd
  from glob import glob
  import os

  DIR = 'Y:\\files\'
  files = glob(os.path.join(DIR, 'DS*.xlsx'))
  files_combined = pd.concat((pd.read_excel(x).assign(filename = x)
       for x in files))
```

but I get the same error.

Comment: I think you should use [] instead of () in pd.concat([pd.read_excel(x).assign(filename = x) for x in files])

Comment: I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I ran this (basically your original code) successfully:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

os.chdir('C:/users/xxxx/')
files = glob('*.xlsx')
files_combined = pd.concat((pd.read_excel(x).assign(filename = x) for x in files))
```

No errors, so I added this and reran:

```
print(files_combined)
```

The result is the concatenation of the 5 xlsx files in my directory.

Then I wanted to test the "no files" option, so I changed my glob statement:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

os.chdir('C:/users/xxxx/')
files = glob('*.xlsx1234')
files_combined = pd.concat((pd.read_excel(x).assign(filename = x) for x in files))
```

Now I get the error "No objects to concatenate".  So a blank list will not return the "list index out of range" error either.

Comment: Could it be because of the file names? They're formatted like x_x_x_x.xlsx. This formula worked for csv files but it's not working for xlsx files